# how to make minutes attribute in a Time class between 0 and 59

Tags: python, object

So I defined a function such that it returns a sum of two `Time` objects as a new `Time` object, but the sum of the minutes in that resulting `Time` object cannot exceed 59 and I don't know how to implement that.

Here's my code:

```
from timer import Time

sum_of_time = Time(0, 0)
sum_of_time.hours= time1.hours + time2.hours
sum_of_time.minutes = time1.minutes + time2.minutes

return sum_of_time

if sum_of_time.minutes >= 60: # where I try to make minutes within 0 to 59
    sum_of_time.minutes = sum_of_time.minutes - 60
    sum_of_time.hours = sum_of_time.hours + 1
    return sum_of_time
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types) is used for.

```
from datetime import timedelta

delta1 = timedelta(hours=1, minutes=30)
delta2 = timedelta(minutes=31)
sum_time = delta1 + delta2
print(sum_time) #2:01:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the quotient and remainder when dividing by 60; the quotient gets added to the hour, and the remainder is used as the number of minutes.

```
sum_of_time = Time(0,0)
hours = time1.hours + time2.hours
minutes = time1.minutes + time2.minutes
q, r = divmod(minutes, 60)  # e.g. divmod(117, 60) == (1, 57)
hours += q
minutes = r
sum_of_time.hours = hours
sum_of_time.minutes = minutes
```

This is logic that should probably be implemented by methods of the `Time` class. For example:

```
class Time:
    def __init__(self, h, m):
        self.hours = 0
        self.minutes = 0

    # For simplicity here, assume other is an instance of Time
    def __add__(self, other):
        hours = self.hours + other.hours
        minutes = self.minutes + other.minutes
        q, r = divmod(minutes, 60)
        return Time(hours + q, r)

sum_of_time = time1 + time2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Time:
    def __init__(self,h,m):
        self.h = h
        self.m = m
        q, r = divmod(m, 60)
        self.h += q
        self.m = r

    def __add__(self, o): 
        return Time(self.h+o.h,self.m+o.m)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}:{1}".format(self.h,self.m)



t1 = Time(1,60)
t2 = Time(1,60)
print (t1+t2)
```